# why google search return results that does not contain the string I searched for?

Tags: google-search

I think google search is not working well any more. I keep getting web pages that does not contain the search string I asked for.

For example, I just typed this in the google main search windows:

```
     "check if a vector"  "range of matrix"
```

Where I wanted to to find pages that contain any or all the above. I used "" to make sure that it finds pages that contains the exact phrase and not individual words.

But when I click on links that show up and search within that page for any of the above search phrases, I do not see them.

Someone told me before that google is adding artificial intelligence in its search and that it tries to guess what the user wants and that can cause false hits.

I am getting more and more annoyed with google search all the time, not giving pages that contain what I am searching for.

Any way to turn this "smart" search of, if it exists, or to explain why this happens?

Comment: I do not understand the down votes on this question. I am showing a serious problem with google search. It seems too many Google employees (or google fans) hanging around here who want to censor any question that shows problem with google search. If you downvote the question, at least explain the reason. If the question is not clear, I will try to improve it.

Comment: I suppose [Super User](http://superuser.com/about) would be a better fit for this question, because it is with respect to power user functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"check if a vector" | "range of matrix"
```

I believe Google was searching for pages with both terms, not one or the other. The pipe (`|`) allows for the functionality you intended.

Edit:

Your search is syntactically correct if you're trying to find both search terms. Another way you could refine your search is to place one of the terms out of the quotes (I'd say the first one because it could be represented in many different ways) and put a plus sign before the second term, in quotes. Like this:

```
check if vector +"range of matrix"
```

This will search for terms related to `check if vector`, and ensure that the results also include `range of matrix`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, that brings up pages that contains one of the 2 phrases. But then the question remains, why did google return pages from `"check if a vector"  "range of matrix"` that contains _both_ of the phrases? If it could not find such a page, should it not at least says so? Currently it returns a result, and the user then thinks it found the pages. But later one finds it did not by looking up the pages. Wasting lots of time. FYI. I actually wanted a page that contains _both_ and not one phrase.

Comment: My apologies for not answering you correctly! It appears that using the original syntax you had only returns seven results, which would indicate that Google is indeed searching for both phrases. Why it doesn't say that it can't find any results? I have no idea. Maybe product satisfaction? But you were indeed searching correctly.

Comment: no problem, your answer was still useful. But it does not explain why google returns search results that does not contain the search query. I think this is what it does: If it can't find pages that contains both search phrases, then it returns pages that it thinks are close to the topic being searched for. But then how is the user to know that? There is no indication that the search failed and the result shown is best guess. This is terrible way to return search result with no indication it failed to find exactly what was searched for.

Comment: See, it's strange, because if I enter a search term like `"garlic mashed potatoes" "google is a search engine"`, it clearly states that there are no results, and then gives me an alternate search query to try out.

Comment: I think your example reinforces my theory of what google is doing. It the search fails, then it tries to guess the subject the user is searching for from all the phrases used. If it can guess, then it returns pages close to the subject. If it can't guess a subject, then it says there is no result and gives an alternative query. With your example, it could not find pages that cover the subject of potatoes and google together. But with my query, it could. Hence the different results.